# How should I use cookies with Svelte and Sapper?

Tags: javascript, sapper, svelte-3

I'm using Svelte and Sapper for a project. Let's say I have some code that needs to read a cookie before it runs, and that code is in a route at say `/profile` or something.

My understanding is that Sapper provides no guarantees where the code will run. If I put the code in regular `<script>` tags or maybe an `onMount` block, when a user requests `/profile` directly from the server, the code still execute on the server (and fail) but then execute again on the client:

```
<script>
import { getCookie } from "../../myUtilities.js";

const myCookieValue = getCookie("myCookie");

async function myRuntimeAction() {
   let res = fetch(`https://www.example.com/api/${myCookieValue}`);
   ...
}
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={myRuntimeAction}>
    <button>
      Take Action!
    </button>
</form>
```

Is there an idiomatic Svelte / Sapper way to guarantee code only runs client-side, when it has access to cookies?

Comment: `way to guarantee code only runs client-side` JS files send from server are runned at client side, cookies are send to server with request - this is all you need.

Comment: In Svelte / Sapper, the code also runs (and fails) server-side.

Comment: What I'm saying if controller sends files to client, they are not interpreted any more at server-side.

Comment: In Svelte + Sapper, that's not accurate. Javascript code will be executed on the client, server, or (usually) both.

Comment: You're suggesting after sending js to client JS comes back to server and it's executed again - I don't think so. Server-side rendering is one thing - JS functionality on client side is another thing.

Comment: Have you used Svelte and Sapper before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204457/discussion-between-nate-vaughan-and-zydnar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two ways to solve this:

## 1. Access cookies inside of functions that will only be executed client-side at runtime

The root of the problem is that my variable declaration was a top-level declaration. Simply moving the code that accesses the cookie inside of a function that is called only at runtime fixes the issue:

```
async function myRuntimeAction() {
   const myCookieValue = getCookie("myCookie");
   let res = fetch(`https://www.example.com/api/${myCookieValue}`);
   ...
}
```

## 2. Check process.browser before trying to access cookies

Svelte exposes `process.browser` to ensure code only executes in the browser:

```
if (process.browser) {
    const myCookieValue = getCookie("myCookie");
}
```